# meanjs app does not load on a 1gig digitalocean droplet

Tags: node.js, deployment, digital-ocean, meanjs, dokku

So here's my setup:

- Digital Ocean 1gig droplet
- Ubuntu 14.04x64
- Dokku 1-click installer
- MongoDB attached to Dokku via https://github.com/jeffutter/dokku-mongodb-plugin. Verified. I can connect to it via robomongo
- domain registered in DNS records in my DigitalOcean dashboard (subdomain.mydomain.com)
- website is accessible (verified via tailed app-access.log)
- the basic meanjs app via their yo generator
- only modified connection to mongodb server in Dokku.
- push to Dokku is successful, no push errors
- DigitalOcean swapfile create (1gig), no memory warnings according to `dokku logs app`
- properly set Dokku env variables verified via `dokku config app`
- properly set VHOST file to mydomain.com

My issue is everytime I visit the site, assets load (up until favicon.ico, along with `/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` and many others from that directory), but it stops there. The site doesn't load anything after that. The favicon shows up then nothing.

I checked the nginx logs, nothing. This is a practice website so I will be posting the nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name mean.ygamretuta.xyz ;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/mean-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/mean-error.log;

  location    / {
    proxy_pass  http://mean;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  include /home/dokku/mean/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;
}
upstream mean { 
  server 172.17.0.62:3000;
}
```

I checked nginx logs, dokku logs, I got nothing. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more googling and I found that I should issue a `grunt build` before I push my code to Dokku residing in Digital Ocean.

here's the discussion in meanjs issues:

https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/64